# Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" at path "payment" in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to update my user model's value by using $inc but when I do this I ge the following error:

`There was an errorCastError: Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" at path "paymentDue"`

**Heres what I am doing**

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
          { _id: req.body.userID },
          {
            $push: { orders: req.body.orderID },
            $inc: { paymentDue: order.quantity * req.body.price },
          },
          (error) => {
            if (!error) {
              res.redirect("/admin/orders");
            } else {
              res.send("There was an error" + error);
            }
          }
        );
```

Comment: It seems `order.quantity * req.body.price` is `NaN`. Have you checked the values of `order.quantity` and `req.body.price`? Chances are, one of them is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you set the default value of the `paymentValue` field to `0`. If it's been already set, either `order.quantity` or `req.body.price` is `undefined`. If you multiply a number with `undefined` the result will be `NaN`. You need to check these values.